# MySQL extracting columns from subquery to append it to main columns

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, conditional-statements, extract

I am a mySQL newbie doing a small project. I will try my best to describe the problem in its entirety so that the pros out here can help me out not only on the code but also the concept. I have never done sql before but have programmed in Python, Matlab, etc. (the procedural environments). Without further ado,

The following code is awfully slow and the if statement

```
if (carts.staffId ='', 'UNASSISTED', 'ASSITED') as EXPERIENCE
```

does not work since it comes out as always *UNASSISTED*. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Here is the code

```
select  
    Impressions.session_id,
    sum(if(Impressions.impressionAction = 'SENDMAIL', 1, 0)) as EMAIL, 
    count(if(Impressions.impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) as SCANS,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(Impressions.createDate), max(Impressions.createDate)) AS Duration,

    if (carts.staffId ='', 'UNASSISTED', 'ASSITED') as EXPERIENCE
    from Impressions, carts
    where Impressions.session_id in (select carts.session_id from carts where carts.session_id <> '' )
    group by Impressions.session_id;
```

The column **staffId** exists in the table called **carts**. All I wanted was to extract an output from a condition on **staffId** in **carts** to be added to the list of columns from the table **Impressions**

Essentially, I am trying to add a column from the subquery and tack it at the end of the main columns from the main query

**UPDATE**: I broke the problem into two pieces and here is how the code looks like. Essentially a UNION between the two outputs creates the final output needed. I just need it in one go:

```
/***********************ASSISTED*******************************/
select  session_id,
    sum(if(impressionAction = 'SENDMAIL', 1, 0)) as EMAIL, 
    count(if(impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) as SCANS,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(createDate), max(createDate)) AS Duration
from Impressions
where session_id in 
    (select session_id
    from carts 
    where session_id <> '' AND staffId <> '' AND staffId <>'ollie' AND staffId<> 'Laura')
        AND createDate >= '2014-06-23'AND createDate < '2014-06-30'
        AND HOUR(createDate) >= 10 AND HOUR(createDate) < 21
        AND impressionId NOT LIKE '%made.com' AND impressionId NOT LIKE '%cloudtags.com%'
group by session_id;



/***************************UNASSISTED***********************/
...everything is same...
    where session_id <> '' AND staffId = '' OR staffId ='ollie' OR staffId= 'Laura' )
...;
```

**2ND UPDATE**
There is one more constraint that I forgot to mention within the `ASSISTTED` vs `UNASSISTED` case. In addition to filtering out the ones here, I will also need to filter out `productId = 1902` from the table `products` that has a `cartID` associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a `CROSS JOIN` operation between `Impressions` and `carts`. (Yes, your query is doing a JOIN operation, it's just using using old school comma syntax to specify the `JOIN` operation.)

And it's a **`CROSS JOIN`** because there's no predicate that "matches" rows between the two tables; every row from `Impressions` is being matching to every row in `carts`.

You've got a `GROUP BY` clause that collapses all the "matched" rows from `carts` to a single row; MySQL picks the values from just a single row in `carts`. And it's choosing the exact same row from `carts` for every row in `Impressions`.

It looks like you'd want to "match" rows in `carts` with rows in `Impressions` using the values in the `session_id` column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT i.session_id
     , SUM(IF(i.impressionAction = 'SENDMAIL', 1, 0)) AS EMAIL
     , COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) AS SCANS
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(i.createDate), MAX(i.createDate)) AS Duration
     , MIN(IF(c.staffId = '', 'UNASSISTED', 'ASSISTED')) AS EXPERIENCE
 FROM Impressions i
 JOIN carts c
   ON c.session_id = i.session_id
  AND c.session_id <> ''
GROUP
   BY i.session_id
```

If there are multiple rows from `carts` with the same matching `session_id`. MySQL is going to choose just a single row, and evaluate the `IF(c.staff_id` expression. (Or, will evaluate that expression for each row, and choose one of the resulting values to return.

That IF expression is testing that `staff_id` is equal to a zero length string (if `staff_id` is numeric, then the literal `''` will be evaluated as numeric value of `0`... but we're only guessing at the actual datatype of `staff_id`.)  If `staff_id` on that row has a value of `NULL`, that will not equal the empty string.

I suspect (but not knowing your use case, so its just a guess) that if *any* `carts` related to the session_id had staff_id entered, that the session is considered "assisted", you'd want to return "ASSISTED". That is, you'd want to return "UNASSISTED" only if *none* of the `carts` had staff_id populated. To get that, I'd wrap that IF expression in a MIN() aggregate function.

---

**EDIT**

Based on the queries added to the question, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT i.session_id
     , SUM(IF(i.impressionAction = 'SENDMAIL', 1, 0)) AS EMAIL
     , COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) AS SCANS
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(i.createDate), MAX(i.createDate)) AS Duration
     , MIN(IF(c.staffId IN ('','ollie','Laura'), 'UNASSISTED', 'ASSISTED')) AS EXPERIENCE
  FROM Impressions i
  JOIN carts c
    ON c.session_id <> ''
   AND c.session_id = i.session_id 
 WHERE i.createDate >= '2014-06-23'
   AND i.createDate < '2014-06-30'
   AND HOUR(i.createDate) >= 10
   AND HOUR(i.createDate) < 21
   AND i.impressionId NOT LIKE '%made.com'
   AND i.impressionId NOT LIKE '%cloudtags.com%'
 GROUP 
    BY i.session_id;
```

Note that if the `staff_id` column has a `NULL` value, the IF expression will return "ASSISTED", because NULL will not equal any of the listed values. To flip that around, so that a NULL would be considered UNASSISTED, we could use a `NOT IN`

```
     , MIN(IF(c.staffId NOT IN ('','ollie','Laura'), 'ASSISTED', 'UNASSISTED')) AS EXPERIENCE
```

Also, the query will *not* return any rows from `Impressions` if there is not a(t least one) corresponding row in `carts`.

We could specify an `OUTER JOIN` if we wanted to return rows from `Impressions` even when there is no matching row in `carts`. We'd specify that by adding the keyword **`LEFT`** before the `JOIN` keyword. Note that if we do add the outer join, then `staff_id` column will be `NULL` whenever a matching row is *not* found in `carts`. (We just want to be sure we handle the potential `NULL` value appropriately in the IF expression.)

**FOLLOWUP NOTES**

We'd only need a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` if we wanted to return a row from `Impressions` that has a `session_id` doesn't appear in any rows in `carts`.

If we always have a row in `carts` for every `session_id` that appears in `Impressions`, you an `[INNER] JOIN` is sufficient A `LEFT JOIN` operation says return rows from the table/rowsource on the "left" side of the join, even if a matching row is not found in the table/rowsoruce on the "right" side. The order of the tables really only matters in terms of a `LEFT|RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`, in terms of which table should be on the "left" side. With an `[INNER] JOIN`, the order of the tables doesn't affect the resultset.

Comment: This is awesome! Let me try this out and see if it works. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It really helped me understand the motivation and heuristics. For instance, I didn't know what you could `JOIN` on two things. I am used to working in SAS and doing things in `data` steps and then doing a `merge`. SQL is a slightly different way of thinking. Can you explain the `NOT IN` part again? I am not sure I understood the flipping part. Also why is there a `MIN` before the `IF`? I recognize simply giving the `IF`doesn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, if you can direct me to some useful resources on getting the intuition behind `JOIN`s, I will be grateful. I learn best through actual examples and short exercises. Most of the resources out there don't do a good job of pumping intuition.

Comment: If there happen to be two rows in `carts` for a given `session_id`, then it's possible that one cart will be "ASSISTED" and other "UNASSISTED"; because of the `GROUP BY`, MySQL will choose one of those to return. I added `MIN()` aggregate to make the result deterministic, in this case, to ensure that "ASSISTED" would be the value returned. The query would work fine (in MySQL, but not other DBMS) without the `MIN()` aggregate function; we just would leave it up to MySQL to decide which row from `carts` is returned (when there is more than one row in `carts` for a given `session_id`.

Comment: The bit about the `NOT IN`,  that was only about handling the case when `c.staffId` is `NULL` (your question doesn't indicate that we are guranteed that `staffId` will be non-NULL.) So, the question is,  if `staffId` is NULL, should we return "ASSISTED" or "UNASSISTED". With the change (to use `NOT IN` instead of `IN`), that just an easy way to return "UNASSISTED" when `staffId` is `NULL`.

Comment: So we are using `LEFT JOIN`here correct? `Impressions` table has multiple lines per  `session_id` but `carts` have 1 line per `session_id`. Should we join `carts` on `impressions` then? Does the order matter? Why?

Comment: I see, then I think we should do an inner join since the original code and the problem is poised to find only the `session_id`s that exists in both tables and are non-empty.

Comment: I am having trouble incorporating the new constraint added. can you please help me? How do I check another table in the `ASSISTED` vs `UNASSISTED` check?

Comment: `IF(c.staffId NOT IN ('','laura','ollie') AND (foo.fee >= 5 OR fi.fo = 'fum'), 'ASSISTED', 'UNASSISTED')`.  It's possible to add additional boolean expressions, combined with boolean `AND` and/or `OR` operators within the `IF` function; the entire expression is evaluated to TRUE or FALSE.  It's also possible to nest `IF` functions, e.g. `IF(i>0,'POSITIVE',IF(i<0,'NEGATIVE',IF(i=0,'ZERO','NULL')))`.

Comment: I *think* I understand it. My biggest problem has been to figure out how to bring say one column `productID` from the table `products`. The tables have the `cartId` as a common key. What I would want is the ability to filter just a `productId` from the `cart`, but not the entire `cart` itself. How and where should I put in the code? In the `if ` of the `where` section?

Comment: To filter the results, to return only rows for a particular product, add a join to the product table, e.g. `JOIN product p ON p.productID = 'someproduct' AND p.cartId = c.cartId`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`, and carts.staffId will be null when there is no match.

```
select  
    Impressions.session_id,
    sum(if(Impressions.impressionAction = 'SENDMAIL', 1, 0)) as EMAIL, 
    count(if(Impressions.impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) as SCANS,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(Impressions.createDate), max(Impressions.createDate)) AS Duration,

    if (carts.staffId is null, 'UNASSISTED', 'ASSITED') as EXPERIENCE
from Impressions
left join carts on Impressions.session_id = carts.session_id
group by Impressions.session_id;
```

You can query part 2 with inner join, and move the experience logic to an `if` function.

```
select  session_id,
    sum(if(impressionAction = 'SENDMAIL', 1, 0)) as EMAIL, 
    count(if(impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) as SCANS,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(createDate), max(createDate)) AS Duration,
    if(b.staffId in ('', 'ollie', 'Laura'), 'UNASSISTED', 'ASSISTED') EXPERIENCE
from Impressions
where session_id a
join carts b on a.session_id = b.session_id
where a.session_id <> '' AND b.createDate >= '2014-06-23'AND b.createDate < '2014-06-30'
    AND HOUR(b.createDate) >= 10 AND HOUR(b.createDate) < 21
    AND b.impressionId NOT LIKE '%made.com' AND b.impressionId NOT LIKE '%cloudtags.com%'
group by a.session_id;
```

Comment: Help me out by explaining the thought process please. I haven't used JOINS yet. Also did you run this? Does it solve the IF statement problem I mentioned. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need some sample data to test it. can you create a [sqlfiddle](sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Let me get to work on that. I have never done a sql fiddle. I ran the code and it runs on my end. However, here is what I did in the meantime. Essentially the union of these two pieces should yield the same result as yours if correct. How would you modify your code to suit the changes (esp the `where` clauses)?

Comment: Character limit reached; please see edit on my initial question.